# Looping issue PHP

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
$TopFive = array_slice($counts,0,5);    
{
  foreach($TopFive as $key => $tops)
{


for($i=0; $i<$tops; $i++)
{
  echo "*";
}

$b=0;   
for($a=0; $a<5; $a++)
{
  $b++; 
}

echo "{$b}";        
echo "#:{$key} - {$tops} <br/>";    


                }
            }
```

currently, the output looks this:

```
*********5#:THE - 9 
*****5#:OF - 5 
*****5#:TO - 5 
***5#:AND - 3 
***5#:THEM - 3
```

but what I really want to have is this:

```
********* #1: THE - 9
***** #2: OF - 5
***** #3: TO - 5
*** #4: AND - 3
*** #5: THEM - 3
```

I can't seem to figure out how to arrange the looping. Any ideas? I am very sorry this simple question, I ran out of ideas. I just want the numbers to be from 1-5.

I just want some advice as to how to arrange the looping for the $b so that the counting will be from 1-5, not just 5

Comment: Can you please post the declaration part of `$TopFive`?

Comment: thanks @Praveen Kumar, that was exactly what I wanted to show. :)

Comment: Welcome, we need to know the value or `var_dump` of `$TopFive` to proceed! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If:

```
$TopFive = array('THE' => 9, 'OF' => 5, 'TO' => 5, 'AND' => 3, 'THEM' => 3);
```

then:

```
$number = 1;

foreach ($TopFive as $word => $count)
{
    echo str_repeat('*', $count); // Outputs '*' characters
    echo " #{$number}: {$word} - {$count}\n";
    $number++; // increment your number
}
```

[Here's an example](http://codepad.org/RdLI3618).

Comment: damn, you answered before me :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Your this line has problem
`for($a=0; $a<5; $a++)`

`$b` always increments to `5`

To solve this, just initialize `$x` (or anything) outside `foreach` loop with `1`. Do away with `$b` and simply `echo $x; $x++;` at appropriate place.

Comment: With that being said, @Vinayak Garg, what should I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to:

```
$b=1;
foreach($TopFive as $key => $tops)
{                                   
    for($i=0; $i<$tops; $i++)
    {
        echo "*";
    }          
    echo "#$b:{$key} - {$tops} <br/>";    
    $b++;
 }
```

but all the inner loops are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, please change this part:

```
echo "{$b}";        
echo "#:{$key} - {$tops} <br/>";
```

To:

```
// echo "{$b}";        
echo "#$i:{$key} - {$tops} <br/>";
```

And use `str_repeat('*', $count)` instead of a `for` loop! :)